# Получение данных с сайта в json формате

Tags: java, android, json

Как делать запросы для получения в приложении данных с сайта в формате json? Как на самом сайте находить ссылки на json? *Нужно с сайта http://openweathermap.org/ получать данные в json о погоде для выбранного в приложении города.*

Comment: Вм сюда http://openweathermap.org/current#current_JSON

Comment: Как в приложении формировать код запроса?

Comment: по той ссылке что я вам дал все написано api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London

Comment: Да я это видел, но не пойму как и где это использовать.
Почему нажимая api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London получаю http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98

Comment: appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98 - это называется токен, все запросы идут с ним, остальное все написано на самом понятном в мире языке. Как читать документацию вас никто не научит.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Может подскажите, что почитать о том, как из  api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London получить в приложении json?

Answer (score 2):

Отправьте заппос соответственно документации сайта. JSON-запрос формируется следующим образом:

```
URL url = new URL("http://yoururl.com");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
//оформление запроса, к примеру {"auth":{"username": adm,"password": pwd},"coord":{"x": 23,"y": 255}}
JSONObject myJSON=new JSONObject();
JSONObject auth=new JSONObject();
auth.put("username","adm"); 
auth.put("password", "pwd");
JSONObject coords=new JSONObject();
coords.put("x", "23");
coords.put("y", "255");
myJSON.put("auth", auth.toString());
myJSON.put("coords", coords.toString());

con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
//отображение результата запроса    
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());  
wr.write(myJSON.toString());
wr.flush();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
int HttpResult = con.getResponseCode(); 
if(HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));  
    String line = null;  
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
        sb.append(line + "\n");  
    }  

    br.close();  

    System.out.println(""+sb.toString());  

}else{
    System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());  
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, меня интересовало, где брать ссылку "http://yoururl.com". В инструкции на сайте, с которого я хотел брать гсон, приведен пример ссылки без токена, подставляя которую в запрос ничего не выводилось. Теперь понял, что нужен обязательно токен.